# "To leave its throne to something else"?

Tags: translation, idiom-requests

I want to define a situation where a certain type of food is the best in my opinion and express this in an idiomatic way.

Would the the following example be completely understood by the native speakers? :

> The X wouldn't leave its throne to any other dish of the night.

Or how would you like to paraphrase the sentence?

Thanks in advance,

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

There are 250 Google hits for "vacate its throne", for example

> If San Diego State's men's basketball team is to surrender, to vacate
>   its throne as defending champion of the Mountain West Conference ...

so this version at least is not unknown. I'd say your example, even if tweaked (note the preposition used in 'he will have to vacate his throne for Nitish' [internet])

> The X won't vacate its throne for any other dish of the night.

sounds acceptable if quirky.

"Leave its throne to [a successor]" only appears in a handful of Google results, perhaps because of the dual possibilities of 'step down in favour of' and 'bequeath to' 'leave to' has.